# Properly convert a JSON response to iterate through it

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I make the following axios call and get the response below it:

```
axios.get('/[my url]/', {
      params: {
        myParam: this.items
      }
    })
```

Response:

```
0   Object { index: 1, var1: 3, var2: 2, … }
    index   1
    var1    3
    var2    2
    var3    480
    var4    5800000
1   Object { index: 1, var1: 4, var2: 4, … } ......
```

I then try to split this response up into an array of objects, with an object for each index value present, and assign that value the this.series array:

```
.then(response => {
        let test = response.data;
        let obj = [];

        test.forEach(function(item) {
          console.log('run: ' + item);
          if(!obj[item.index]) {
            obj[item.index] = {
              name: item.index,
              type: 'scatter',
              data: []
            };
          }
          obj[item.index].data.push(
            [
              parseFloat(item.var3),
              parseFloat(item.var4)
            ]
          );
          delete item.index;
        });

        this.series = obj;
      })
```

Here is the part I don't understand. The code above does not work and prints this to console:

```
run: [object Object]
```

so it only runs once.
When I replace the console.log with `console.log('run: ' + item.var4);`
it then runs the right amount of times, but the `obj` variable still does not populate properly.

Any insights as to why this is happening?

Comment: Are you sure it's not showing something like `run: [object Object] (5)`? Browser consoles tend to combine multiple copies of the same log into one entry with a count.

Comment: I think you're right, I added an integer to keep count of runs and it works fine, you just let me realize that the issue is with my item.index -> these indexes do not start at 0, but can be any number, so the array at the end does not have a 0 index. Is there an easy way to make all indexes start at 0 and increment with one?

Comment: guessing here you meant `obj[item.index].data = obj[item.index].data.concat` and not `push`

Comment: Depending on your intention, you could do `item.index - 1` or you could use `Object.values(obj)`

Comment: Or, `newIndex = Math.max(item.index, obj.length)`.  Note there is a (somewhat) subtle difference between these 3.

Comment: Did you convert the original result using `response.json()`? And `delete item.index` seems not like a goog idea within the loop. Also you might want to use the `reduce` function of arrays instead of `forEach`.